how to mock tracing in scala using open telemetry
object Main {

private val tracerInjector = Guice.createInjector(new TracingModule)
implicit val tracer: Tracer = tracerInjector.getInstance(classOf[Tracer])

private val testInjector: Injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServiceModule)
private val testService = testInjector.getInstance(classOf[TestService])

private val controller = new testController(tracer)

//akka server implementation 
}

class testController @Inject() (tracer: Tracer)  
def testRoute: Route = {
    path("test-route") {
      val span = tracer.spanBuilder("test-Route: Span").startSpan()
      span.addEvent("testing routes"
        , Attributes.builder().put("GET", "/test-route").build())
      get {
        span.addEvent("testing routes 2")

        val getResponse: Future[String] = ask(parentActor, TestCase((tracer, span))).mapTo[String]

        span.end()
        complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    }
  }  



final case class TestCase(tracer:(Tracer, Span))
class ActorManager extends Actor {
 def recevie {
 
 case TestCase(tracer) =>
      val childSpan = tracer._1.spanBuilder("Actor-Manager: ChildSpan")
        .setParent(Context.current.`with`(tracer._2)).startSpan()
      childSpan.addEvent("TestCase 1")
      senderRef = Some(sender())
      generateGroundTruthForDrivingLicenseActor ! TestCase2(tracer)

      childSpan.addEvent("TestCase 1")
      childSpan.end()

 
 }
}  

class ChildActor @Inject()(testService: TestServiceTrait) extends Actor {
def receive: Receive = {

case TestCase2(tracer) =>
      val childSpan = tracer._1.spanBuilder("TestCase2: ChildSpan")
        .setParent(Context.current.`with`(tracer._2)).startSpan()
      childSpan.addEvent("TestCase2 calling service method")
      testService.testMethod(tracer)
      childSpan.end()
}
}

trait TestServiceTrait {
  def testMethod(tracer:(Tracer, Span)):Boolean
}

class TestService {
 override def testMethod(tracer:(Tracer, Span)):Boolean = {
    val childSpan = tracer._1.spanBuilder("renameCrops-Method-in-Service: ChildSpan")
      .setParent(Context.current.`with`(tracer._2)).startSpan()
    childSpan.addEvent("testMethod")
    childSpan.end()
    true
  }
}

object MockTracer extends TracerTrait {

  val inMemoryExporter = InMemorySpanExporter.create()

  private val labelSet: Attributes = Attributes.builder().put("service.name", "notary-training-ocr-test").build()

  private val tracerProvider: SdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder()
    .addSpanProcessor(SimpleSpanProcessor.create(inMemoryExporter))
    .setResource(Resource.create(labelSet))
    .build()

  private val openTelemetry: OpenTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
    .setTracerProvider(tracerProvider)
    .build()

  override def tracer: Tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer("ocrTestTracer")

}

class TestClass extends AnyWordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with MockFactory with JsonSupport {
  implicit val defaultTimeout: RouteTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(600.seconds)
val drivingLicenseTrainService: DrivingLicenseTrainServiceTrait = mock[DrivingLicenseTrainServiceTrait]
val tracer = MockTracer.tracer
  
  
  val controller = new testController(tracer)
  
  "The Service" should {
    "generate ground truth files POST request with path /generate-driving-license-ground-truth-mode" in {

      val expectedModelName = "eng"  // Set the value you expect for modelName

      val span = MockTracer.tracer.spanBuilder("test ground truth Span").startSpan()
      span.addEvent("create ground truth functionality "
        , Attributes.builder().put("GET", "/generate-driving-license-ground-truth-model").build())

      val tracer_touple = (tracer,span)
 
      (drivingLicenseTrainService.testMethod _)
        .expects(tracer_touple)
        .returning(true)
        .anyNumberOfTimes()

      Get("/test-route") ~> drivingLicenseTrainingController.routes ~> check {
        status shouldEqual StatusCodes.OK
        info("status code matched")
      }
      span.end()
    }
  }
}

when I run the test I got the following exception
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Unexpected call: <mock-1> TestServiceTrait.testMethod((io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracer@34252032,SdkSpan{traceId=bda0de82b71e2d40ab73ce47dd7bbc5d, spanId=b9cdbf86f8a2d49b, parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, name=test-Route: Span, kind=INTERNAL, attributes=null, status=ImmutableStatusData{statusCode=UNSET, description=}, totalRecordedEvents=2, totalRecordedLinks=0, startEpochNanos=1726233760709644000, endEpochNanos=0}))

Expected:
inAnyOrder {
  <mock-1> TestServiceTrait.testMethod((io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracer@34252032,SdkSpan{traceId=67f3f71146238885eb25b1174cc7aa5b, spanId=2cd26dc2e079eabc, parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, name=test ground truth Span, kind=INTERNAL, attributes=null, status=ImmutableStatusData{statusCode=UNSET, description=}, totalRecordedEvents=1, totalRecordedLinks=0, startEpochNanos=1726233760547292000, endEpochNanos=0})) any number of times (never called)
}

Actual:
  <mock-1> TestServiceTrait.testMethod((io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracer@34252032,SdkSpan{traceId=bda0de82b71e2d40ab73ce47dd7bbc5d, spanId=b9cdbf86f8a2d49b, parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, name=test-Route: Span, kind=INTERNAL, attributes=null, status=ImmutableStatusData{statusCode=UNSET, description=}, totalRecordedEvents=2, totalRecordedLinks=0, startEpochNanos=1726233760709644000, endEpochNanos=1726233760718052915}))
    at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory.newExpectationException(AbstractMockFactory.scala:51)
    at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory.newExpectationException$(AbstractMockFactory.scala:50)
    at trainingtests.drivinglicense.TestClass.newExpectationException(TestClass.scala:31)
    at trainingtests.drivinglicense.TestClass.newExpectationException(TestClass.scala:31)
    at org.scalamock.context.MockContext.reportUnexpectedCall(MockContext.scala:42)
    at org.scalamock.context.MockContext.reportUnexpectedCall$(MockContext.scala:41)
    at trainingtests.drivinglicense.TestClass.reportUnexpectedCall(TestClass.scala:31)
    at org.scalamock.function.MockFunction.onUnexpected(MockFunction.scala:30)
    at org.scalamock.function.MockFunction.onUnexpected$(MockFunction.scala:30)
    at org.scalamock.function.MockFunction1.onUnexpected(MockFunction.scala:43)
    at org.scalamock.function.MockFunction1.onUnexpected(MockFunction.scala:43)
    at org.scalamock.function.FakeFunction.$anonfun$handle$1(FakeFunction.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.scalamock.function.FakeFunction.handle(FakeFunction.scala:44)
    at org.scalamock.function.FakeFunction1.apply(FakeFunction.scala:63)
    at trainingtests.drivinglicense.TestClass$$anon$1.testMethod(TestClass.scala:56)
    at training.trainingmodels.drivinglicenses.actors.worker.ChildActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ChildActor.scala:38)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)


What is unclear to you in the error? You've got different IDs in the real vs. expected. You should likely assert on specific items but ignore the IDs.

Could you please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example?
